# MarionetteJS - cannot reference this in template function

Tags: backbone.js, this, marionette

I have a view which is a Marionette ItemView. I would like to access other parameters on this view using **"this"** inside the template function but I get it as undefined and I'm unsure why.

```
define(['jquery', 'hbs!templates/template', 'backbone'],
    function ($, template, Backbone) {
        "use strict";

        return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

            name: "Depth",

            el: ".card",

            template: function(serializedModel){
                var self = this; // self is undefined, so I can't reference this.name, which would be Depth

                var data = {isDepth: true, cardTitle: self.name, injectHTML: template()}; 

                .... do some stuff ...

                return template();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use underscore's bindAll to bind template to your marionetteItem View's this whenever its called . So something like :

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'template');
    },
    template: function() {
        //this refers to the parent object scope.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use templateHelpers to access custom variables in the template:

```
templateHelpers:function(){ 
    return { 
        card_title: this.name 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm kinda new at marionette

Comment: Sure in the template helpers function (method of the view) you can access properties that are bound to the view object. Check the updated answer, this might give you more understanding. Now you can access the card_title property directly in the template.

Comment: thanks for the update. Now how would I access the template helper function in the template function?

Comment: Hi it depends on what you use as templating engine. I use Underscore, in this case you can access the variable using the regular syntax: `<%= card_title %>`